# XgBoost on Android

Tags: r, android, machine-learning, xgboost

I've noticed that XgBoost supports multiple OSs, such as MacOS, Ubuntu, Windows etc. The installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md). However, I do not see any instructions for Android. Has anyone tried this (or tried to "hack" to accomplish this)?

Comment: Why would you want to run this on an Android device? And it seems it is written in Python, so you'll need find a way to run that on the JVM.

Comment: @Flummox, under the hood xgboost is coded in c++, with interfaces to python and other languages. I need a high performance random forest implementation for an app I'm working on.

Comment: @Leeor: Did you have any luck running Xgboost on Android or iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this [xgboost-predictor-java](https://github.com/komiya-atsushi/xgboost-predictor-java), Just adding the dependencies in android studio. 
For instruction you can follow the [readme.md](https://github.com/komiya-atsushi/xgboost-predictor-java/blob/master/README.md) file

Comment: Can this be used for training or only prediction?

Comment: only used for prediction because it takes model as a input, and not making model it's own